# lxc access to juju-local instances

Tags: juju, lxc, lxd

After creating instances with lxc, we can list them with:

```
lxc list
```

juju-local creates its instances on lxc containers, which are visible through *juju status*. But why do these instances not appear on the previous command (*lxc list*)?

Using:
juju version 1.25.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juju 1.25.x uses lxc 1 so you will be able to see those instances using `lxc-ls --fancy`. The command you're running `lxc list` is using lxd which is used by Juju 2.x.

You can get Juju 2 by following the instructions here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started-general

Comment: Aha! I now I got it. But, by default it needs sudo rights... *sudo lxc-ls*